# Spark + Yarn: How to retain logs of lost-executors

Tags: hadoop, logging, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Working with `Spark` configured with `Yarn` (in `client` mode, though not much relevant to the question), I found that some of my `Executors` are failing.

The `Executor`, which is a `Yarn-Container`, has its individual log file at: `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/containerID`. Some of the (critical) events/logs generated by the container percolates to the driver, but not all of them. It is observed that when an `Executor` fails, its `log file` is cleared up as soon as it dies. Is there any way to keep these logs from getting deleted for debug purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Since, you have spark on yarn, I hope this would help to gather all the logs

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>
```

Comment: No, it seems to work after the job is finished. So can't get the logs from lost executors.

Comment: When you say lost executors, its the node is lost or your code failed at a specific executor

Comment: At the moment I am facing both issues. Executor failure is a bit frequent, and node lost is quite rare. My intent is to be certain on what exactly happened inside the container/executor. I get exit status codes of 137, 50 and 100 with some "reason" which has minimal details.. But not sure how to make sense out of it.

Comment: The above yarn command will help you to get all the executor logs and driver logs that occurred for that application id. That includes any debugging info or exceptions which occurred. And ideally  node should not be lost, unless you face memory issues.

Comment: Tried already, it does not include container logs for lost executor. You can try this on your setup by manually killing an executor. In case it works for you, probably I am missing some configuration. Btw, I am using EMR machines, r3xl, with default yarn-site.xml